# Switch structure in C++ not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void student_array();
void query();
void show_arr();
void student_entry();


struct student
{
    char name[80];
    char f_name[80];
    char the_class[3];
    char grade[2];
};

student std_arr[10];
char action;
int count;
int main()
{
    cout<<"add 1st student"<<endl;
    student_entry();
}
void student_entry()
{
    if (count == 10)
    {
        cout<<"Memory Full!";
        //break;
    }
    cout<<"enter name of student"<<endl;
    cin>>std_arr[count].name;
    //cout<<std_arr[count].name;
    cout<<"enter student's father's name"<<endl;
    cin>>std_arr[count].f_name;
    cout<<"enter the class of student"<<endl;
    cin>>std_arr[count].the_class;
    cout<<"enter the grade of student"<<endl;
    cin>>std_arr[count].grade;
    query();
    count++;

}

void query()
{
    cout<<"what do you want to do?"<<endl;
    cout<<"press a to add"<<endl;
    cout<<"press s to show"<<endl;
    cout<<"press q to quit"<<endl;
    cin>>action;
    //cout<<action;
    switch (action)
    {
        case 'a':
        {
            student_entry();
            break;
        }
        case 's':
        {
            show_arr();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout<<"wrong entry";
            query();
            break;
        }
    }
}

void show_arr()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Student No."<<count<<endl;
        cout<<"Name: "<<std_arr[i].name<<endl;
        cout<<"Father's Name: "<<std_arr[i].f_name<<endl;
        cout<<"Class: "<<std_arr[i].the_class<<endl;
        cout<<"Grade Achieved: "<<std_arr[i].grade<<endl;
    }
}
```

My switch structure is not calling the show_arr() function on the case of s.

Comment: where is the part of the switch that handles q?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the variable `count` before calling `query` otherwise the `for` loop is not executed. Since one student is already added to the array it makes sense to increment this variable before doing query.

Answer (score 1):

`count` is always zero.

First time when you call `student_entry` from `main`, you are calling `query` before incrementing the value of `count`. Now if you enter `a`, the next student's data will be entered at `str_arr[0]` itself and `query` is called without updating `count`.

Hence whenever you enter `'s'` and the function `show_arr` is called, value of  `count` would be zero.

Don't call query from the student_entry method, just increment count and return from it. Do querying in a `while(true)` loop in the main function and call `student_entry` or `show_data` or just `break` out based on entered data.